How to assign the stack/heap area into the external ram
How could I assign the stack/heap area into the external RAM on the KEIL SDK.
My scatter file is like the following.
LR_IROM1 0x01008000 0x00400000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x01008000 0x00400000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_SRAM1 0x60000000 0x02000000  {  ; RW data
;   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
   *(foo1)
   *(foo2)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00010000  {
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}

The internal ram area is 0x20000000 + 0x00010000 and
the external ram area is 0x60000000 + 0x02000000.
I want to assign only the stack/heap area in the external RAM.
